# sklearn matching results become misaligned when the data sets increase

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

I've been using sklearn NearestNeighbors to do name matching and at a certain point the results become misaligned. My standardized list of names is 100s of millions.  My list of names coming in to be matched is considerably smaller but still could be in the 250k to 500k range.  After a certain point it appears the index begins to shift by 1 or more.

```
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, n_jobs=-1).fit(tfidf) 
unique_org = set(names['VariationName'].values) # set used for increased performance
#matching query:
def getNearestN(query):
  queryTFIDF_ = vectorizer.transform(query)
  distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(queryTFIDF_)
  return distances, indices

print('Getting nearest n...')
distances, indices = getNearestN(unique_org)

unique_org = list(unique_org) #need to convert back to a list
print('Finding matches...')
matches = []
for i,j in enumerate(indices):
  temp = [round(distances[i][0],2), clean_org_names.values[j][0][0],unique_org[i]]
  matches.append(temp)

print('Building data frame...')  
matches = pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['Match confidence (lower is better)','Matched name','Original name'])
print('Data frame built')
```

It appears that once my standardized list gets over 80k it begins to shift the results down.

The "messy name" of VITALI, ANGELO (has a comma)

```
VITALI, ANGELO
```

The standardized list of names may include these(no comma)

```
VITALI ANGELO   
SENSABLE TECHNOLOGIES INC
```

After running it through the above matching the result below shows that VITALI, ANGELO is a near perfect match to SENSABLE TECNOLOGIES INC, because the index has shifted down one...I think.

```
 0.00   SENSABLE TECHNOLOGIES INC   VITALI, ANGELO
```

Is it possible that the size or number of records is  exceeding that matrix limits and it somehow messes the indices?

Comment: When limiting my "name" column to only 50 characters the limit raises from 80k to roughly 250k in the standardized list before it starts having miss aligned results.  It seems like there is a limit somewhere I can't nail down.  Either server memory or the python variables being used.  Still searching.

Comment: You're making a `set` out of the names. If there are duplicates, they will be dropped, which may result in things shifting around.

Comment: It's not clear that this isn't more of a bug report than a programming question, but either way you are more likely to get help if you can provide a sample dataset that replicates the problem.  Otherwise, this forces any potential answerers to first spend time trying to replicate the problem (without knowing if they'll even succeed at that part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets don't guarantee preservation of order in general. So the order in which `getNearestN` iterated through `unique_org` may not be the same order that the `list` constructor did:

```py
distances, indices = getNearestN(unique_org)  # computed distances with respect to an unordered set

unique_org = list(unique_org) # `unique_org` was potentially shuffled here
```

Instead try it with lists and see if that works. If it's a lot slower with lists, I suspect the culprit is duplicate names rather than sets being better suited for the job. You can handle duplicates in pandas (`names['VariationName'].unique()`), or in vanilla python (`list(set(names['VariationName']))`).

So to summarize, I'd make sure I don't have duplicates (probably using pandas), and then use lists throughout and see if it works.

Source:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

[python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would like to add that if lists don't work in terms of speed, you can use the OrderedSet class from here: https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/ - This class is specifically designed to be friendly with pandas.

Comment: I was thinking of mentioning that, but I didn't think OrderedSets would be faster for iteration anyway. Aren't they optimized for existence checking and such, whereas lists are more optimized for iteration? I mean, I find it very hard to believe that the bottle-neck is the `unique_org` data-structure anyway.